# Accessing to iBooks library (iOS)

Tags: ios, ibooks

Is it possible to access to the iBooks library from custom application? Like MPMediaPickerController for music/video? Or having access to the books which sync with iTunes.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to access this information. Apple allows some protocols to make calls to other system applications, but iBooks is not one of them.

Comment: Its very strange approach from Apple. Because iTunes syncs books even iBooks app was not installed. So books are in the phone but nothing can't access those?

Comment: No, Apple doesn't allow applications to reach outside the bounds of their memory container to access information from other apps (save for some future iOS8 extensions) or anything from the file structure.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such API.